# Setting up a proxy connection for R3.2 or RStudio in Windows 7?

Tags: r, proxy, wininet, bioconductor, http-status-code-407

I am a first-time user for R and a newbie in R programming. I was trying to install Bioconductor. However, I got the 407 error everytime. I read the download.file according to which "wininet" is the preferred method for windows to set a proxy.
To use wininet for setting up a proxy connection with my authentication details, what are the steps I should follow?

It will be very helpful and other beginners if the answer is provided in a detailed, step-wise manner.
Thank you very much.

P.S. I have tried adding the http proxy details in the R shortcut path, but it didn't work.